# Show geojson featureCollection with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, map-projections

with QGIS I´ve exported a polygon layer as geojson which I´d like to publish with leaflet. This is how the geojson looks like [*exluded due to SO character limits*]:
https://gist.github.com/t-book/88806d12d7f05024b147715be82e6844

**This is what I´ve tried:**

Wrapped geojson as var:

```
var states = [{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31468" } },
    "features": [
       { "type": "Feature", "properties": ...
}];
```

Added as new Layer:

```
L.geoJSON(states, {
    style: function(feature) {
        switch (feature.properties.party) {
            case 'Euerbach': return {color: "#ff0000"};
            case 'Werneck':   return {color: "#0000ff"};
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Unfortunately nothing is rendered. How do I correctly add this geojson featureCollection to my map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your data is projected - Leaflet is expecting your data to be unprojected (composed of long/lat pairs, or "projected" in WGS84/EPSG 4326). There are a few solutions, two come to mind here:

- In QGIS, export your data so that it is composed of long/lat coordinate pairs
- Use proj4.js to reproject your coordinates when displaying the geojson.

For number two, you'll need to set the coordsToLatLng option when adding the geojson as a layer:

```
var geojson = L.geoJSON(states, {
    coordsToLatLng: function (p) {  
        // return get lat/lng point here.
})
```

The body of this function will take a coordinate in the geojson's coordinate reference system (CRS) and return it in WGS84 using proj4.

Also, coordsToLatLng function expects you to return lat/long pairs. As your geojson and proj4 represent data that is [x,y], we need to swap our values before returning the new point.

This could look like:

```
var geojson = L.geoJSON(states, {
    coordsToLatLng: function (p) {
        p = proj4(fromProjection,toProjection,p);  // reproject each point
        p = [p[1],p[0]]    // swap the values
        return p;          // return the lat/lng pair
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Of course, we need to define our CRSs. I looked up your CRS (it is specified in the geojson itself) on [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/31468/proj4/) and used the provided description for that CRS and EPSG4326 (WGS84) to set my fromProjection and toPojection:

```
var fromProjection = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs ';
var toProjection = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ";
```

Altogether that gives us something [like this](http://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/e472886c83819e8459178a4a56548449).
Keep in mind, that if you have large files, reprojecting them in javascript will take longer than if you export them in the proper CRS.